Design protocol for logarithm with arithmetic secret sharing
My question is about designing a protocol for logarithm, or any other non-linear function. In arithmetic secret sharing, an input $x$ is split into $x_i$ shares. And all of them are in a finite field $\mathbb F_p$. To express these shares, the common practice is predefined a fixed point format or floating point format. However, when calculating logarithm, the value ranges of inputs and outputs are quite different.
For example, if we use IEEE Float754, the maximum input is $3.4\times10^{38}$ and the minimal input is $1.18\times10^{-38}$. Consequently, the maximum output is only about $\log(3.4\times 10^{38})\approx91.0246$ and the minimal output is $\log(1.8\times 10^{-38})\approx-84.6079$.
Similarly, in another case using int64 to express 16-bit-precision fixed-point number. Then the maximum output is $\log(2^{48})\approx33.2711$ and the minimal output is $\log(2^{-16})\approx-11.0904$.
Therefore, even if the designed protocol outputs secret shares in $\mathbb F_p$ to different parties, they still know that the actual value must be in a much smaller range.
So a possible scenario would be like the following. I want to calculate $\log_3(81)$, and two parties hold one share each. Let's say $p_0$ has $3221$ and $p_1$ has $-3140$. In MPC, we would like them get output shares, i.e., $-1008$ and $1012$. What worries me is that even though they hold shares in a large field ($-1008$ and $1012$), they know the actual result value must be within a much smaller range. In this example, suppose they are using fixed-point, they then know the actual value must be within [-11.0904, 33.2711]. Hence, they can reduce the shares to $-8$ and $12$.
It seems like they can even enumerate all the possible results in that smaller range. So I wonder whether such prior knowledge could be a threat to the security? If not, how can I prove it?

Secret sharing (e.g Shamir's) is not the multiparty computation of some function. It shares a pre-established quantity. That quantity can be a bitstring. An IEEE-754 floating point number can be represented as a bitstring, and safely shared as such. If the question considers an actual multiparty-computation rather than mere secret sharing, please describe more precisely the functionality to be achieved.
